# Can I mention the LinkedIn account of a suggested referee?

Tags: publications

I'm submitting an article to an Elsevier journal which asks for suggested potential referee list. One of the people whom I want to suggest as the referee is a doctor and instructor in a university. I have found his page in the corresponding university, but unfortunately the page is not written in English. Unfortunately there is no other English written pages for his introduction except his LinkedIn page.

Since it's common to provide an introduction page and the email address of the suggested referees, Is it OK if I mention the LinkedIn page of the referee that I want to suggest? Should I provide his web page in the university that he is working too (The page is not written in English)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't harm if you include the web address of his/her current institution in addition to his LinkedIn profile address.  Depending on the scientific field, a publisher this huge as Elsevier has  boards of editors from many countries where English is not the primary mean of communication, too; so his site may be accessible for them.  (Even if written in an other script than latin like e.g., from Japan, Korea, China, Russia, Israel.)

To strengthen your suggestion he could serve as a referee, maybe earlier and current work is clearly attributed to him by an identifier like [ORCID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ORCID) or [ResearcherID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ResearcherID)/[Publons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publons).  It is unique in the sense that it won't change if he changes the workplace or (e.g., by marriage) changes the name; especially if his name is one of the more frequently seen ones (e.g., Smith, Li, etc.).  Because there are data bases allowing to search by this criterion both the publications, as well who cited these, the editor could see quickly the potential referee's connection to the relevant community, too; thus, if accessible, *include it*, too.

Comment: How about his/her google scholar?

Comment: @Pablo If there is, yes. Maybe there s/he chaired a session at IEEE (as example of a specialized professional community) and joined their registry, too. The _point_ mentioning Publons (the off-spring of ResearcherID by Clarivate's Web of Science) and ORCID (not behind a pay-wall) earlier was (and is) to ease the editor's indentification that s/he is suitable to serve as referee because a) his / her work / interest is related to the context of your publication or / and b) maybe for other authors than you.